# Monochrome image getting displayed as colored RGB image

Tags: windows, image, visual-c++, bitmap, mfc

Bitmap is constructed by pixel data(purely pixel data). The construction was done by properly setting the bitmap parameters like hieght,width, bitcount etc. Bitmap is actually constructed with CreateDIBsection. And the bitmap is loaded onto a CStatic object having Bitmap as property.

Image is getting displayed with proper width and content. But only difference is the content color is colored instead of scale of gray. For eg image is a white H letter on black Bground, instead of displaying it as whitish, say a blue colored H letter is displayed. Similar color changes applies for different images. Also, sometimes junk colored data appears deviating from original content of image apart from just the color change.

Bitmap is a 16 bit bitmap.

Please see below for code used for creating BitMap.

HDC is device context of CStatic variable in which the created bitmap is loaded;
I directly set the BitMap returned by below function to this variable using setbitmap function. CStatic varibale has also BitMap as one of its property. See below for function used to create bitmap.

Function parameter definitions.
PixMapHeight = number of rows in pixel matrix.
PixMapWidth = number of columns in pixel matrix.
BitsPerPixel = The bits stored for one pixel.
pPixMapBits = Void pointer to pixel array.(raw pixel data only! 16 bit per pixel).
DoBitmapFromPixels(HDC Hdc, UINT PixMapWidth, UINT PixMapHeight, UINT BitsPerPixel, LPVOID pPixMapBits)

```
    BITMAPINFO *bmpInfo = (BITMAPINFO *)malloc(sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * 256);
    BITMAPINFOHEADER &bmpInfoHeader(bmpInfo->bmiHeader);
    bmpInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    LONG lBmpSize = PixMapWidth * PixMapHeight * (BitsPerPixel / 8);
    bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = PixMapWidth;
    bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = -(static_cast<int>(PixMapHeight));
    bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = BitsPerPixel;
    bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    void *pPixelPtr = NULL;
    HBITMAP hBitMap = CreateDIBSection(Hdc, bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pPixelPtr, NULL, 0);
    if (pPixMapBits != NULL)
    {
        BYTE* pbBits = (BYTE*)pPixMapBits;
        BYTE *Pix = (BYTE *)pPixelPtr;
        memcpy(Pix, ((BYTE*)pbBits + (lBmpSize * (CurrentFrame - 1))), lBmpSize);
    }
    free(bmpInfo);
    return hBitMap;
```

The supposed output is the figure in the left of attached file. But I am getting a blue toned image as in right(never mind the scaling and exact match issue,  put the image to depict the problem).

[image: MismatchImage]

**And also it will be very helpful if I know how RGB values are stored in 16 bits!**

Comment: There's insufficient information here to answer, but I'd predict that you have a single 8-bit channel, and it's being displayed with the default palette, which is not a grayscale palette.

Comment: Maybe you should show both pictures, the one as it is displayed and another one that looks as you expect.

Comment: You say it's a 16 bit bitmap, so it's not monochrome. (Monochrome means one bit per pixel. Once you fix that, you need to be aware that blitting monochrome bitmaps into a color destination uses text and background colors to map black and white.)

Comment: Hint: Provide relevant code. Why should we trust you, when you say, things are properly set up? After all, your code is failing, and that's a strong indication, that something is wrong.

Comment: I have added the necessary. @MichaelWalz , I have attached the picture. Sorry for the incomplete question, I though my problem was a trivial one at first!

Comment: @RaymondChen, Monochrome image can be constructed with RGB values, right? Afterall any color can be represented in R G B values. I guess that is the case I am dealing with now.

Comment: *Monochrome* (when used with bitmaps) means: 1 bit per pixel, and the rules have been explained by Raymond Chen above. The image you posted isn't monochrome, but rather a *grayscale* image. Different rules apply.

Answer (score 1):

You never actually said what format `pPixMapBits` is in, but I'm guessing that it contains 16-bit values where 0 represents black, 32768 represents gray, and 65535 represents white.

You are creating a `BITMAPINFOHEADER` with `bitBitCount = 16` and `biCompression = BI_RGB`. According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx), if you set the fields that way, then:

> Each **WORD** in the bitmap array represents a single pixel. The relative intensities of red, green, and blue are represented with five bits for each color component. The value for blue is in the least significant five bits, followed by five bits each for green and red. The most significant bit is not used.

This is not the same format as your source data, and you are doing no conversion, so you get junk. Note that the bitmap format you chose is capable of representing only 2^5 = 32 shades of gray, not 65536, so you will suffer loss of quality during the conversion.

Comment: Note also that your calculation of `lBmpSize` is incorrect if the `PixMapWidth` is an odd number. From the documentation: "[The scan lines are DWORD aligned, except for RLE-compressed bitmaps. They must be padded for scan line widths, in bytes, that are not evenly divisible by four, except for RLE compressed bitmaps.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183386(v=vs.85).aspx)"

Comment: How can I construct the bitmap image in grayscale? I used BI_RGB as the image is uncompressed. Have also tried BI_BITFIELDS. doesn't work either. And one more thing, there is no loss of data, not a bit. Grey scale image is getting displayed in blue scale image.

Comment: PixMapWidth always come as even for the sort of images that I am dealing with.

Comment: You still haven't said what format your source data is in. Whatever it is, convert it to 555.

Comment: @ScarCode bitmaps don't have an inherent gray-scale format. You either need to set up a palette, or copy the gray-scale values three times to R,G,B pixels. If you require 16-bit gray values, that implies 48 bits per pixel, and I'm not sure that's a native format either.